# Find CDF of $Y=-X+2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

i have a task to find CDF of $Y=-X+2$, while:

$\begin{align}F_X (x) & = \begin{cases} 0 & :x \leq 0 \\ \tfrac 12x & : 0\lt x \leq 2 \\ 1 & : x\gt 2\end{cases}\end{align}$

i did something like this:

$P(Y<x) = P(-X+2<x)=P(X>-x+2)=1-P(X<-x+2)=1-F_X(-x+2)$

and i have no idea what to do in the next step. I've heard i need to define specific ranges for the arguments in $F_Y$ but i dont know how to do that. I have tried a lot of things but i still haven't got the right answear.

The answear i have to get is:

$\begin{align}F_Y (x) & = \begin{cases} 0 & :x \leq 1 \\ \tfrac 12x & : 1\lt x \leq 2 \\ 1 & : x\gt 2\end{cases}\end{align}$

Comment: Maybe try drawing it? It might make things clearer

Comment: The answer that you quote is wrong. The first line should be $0: x\le 0$, not $0: x \le 1$. (In fact $F_Y$ is identical to $F_X$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.

Since $P(Y<x)=1-F_X(-x+2)=\begin{cases}1=1-0& -x+2\le 0\\1-\frac 12(-x+2)&0< -x+2\le 2\\ 1-1&-x+2>2\end{cases}$
as you noticed, we have $$F_Y(x)=\begin{cases}0&x<0\\\frac 12 x&0\le x< 2\\ 1& x\ge 2\end{cases}.$$

Comment: I did something like this in my first try but the answear is a little bit different. I posted it above. I don't understand why there is 1 instead of 0.

Comment: @BindedFortunes Notice that $-x+2>2$ gives us $x<0$, so...

Comment: Yeah, i understand i just wasn't sure because of the answer i have in my book. It's not for the first time there is a wrong answer. Thank you so much for your help.